# how to save a matrix as an image in Julia in 2018

Tags: image, matrix, julia

This is a trivial question, of course, but I'm having a hard time finding a working answer.

Given a matrix A ( either 2d for grayscale, or 3d for RGB) how to save it on the disk as an image file using **Julia**?

I have an old code written in 2016 when I would use

```
save("filename.png",Images.colorim(matrix_A))
```

Now this seems to be gone for good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could use `colorview` to view your raw matrix as an image and then save it.

```
julia> using Images

julia> save("gray.png", colorview(Gray, rand(256,256)))
```

[image]

```
julia> save("rgb.png", colorview(RGB, rand(3,256,256)))
```

[image]

Comment: With Julia v.1.1 and Images v0.17.3 this produces the error `ERROR: FileIO.File{FileIO.DataFormat{:UNKNOWN}}("gray.png") couldn't be recognized by FileIO.`

Comment: @Mankka cannot reproduce it with ImageMagick backend

Comment: I hade to use `save(File(format"PNG", "gray.png"), colorview(Gray, rand(256,256)))` to make it work. I wonder what difference in our systems produces this error...

Comment: @Mankka probably, I only tested it on Windows.